# python igraph write_dot function fails to write but write_svg succeeds. Am I using write_dot incorrectly?

Tags: python, igraph

I am trying to use python-igraph version 0.6-1 to plot directed graphs in dot format.

I get an empty dot file when using the write_dot function in the program below. However write_svg writes a proper svg file and ig.plot shows the graph correctly.

Whats going on?

> import igraph as ig
>
> g = ig.Graph()
>   g.add_vertex('foo')
>   g.add_vertex('bar')
>   g.add_vertex('baz')
>   g.add_edge('foo', 'bar')
>   g.add_edge('bar','baz')
>   g.add_edge('baz', 'foo')
>   lyt = g.layout_reingold_tilford()
>   ig.plot(g, layout=lyt)
>   g.write_dot('test.dot')
>   g.write_svg('test.svg', lyt)

Comment: Works for me in `python-igraph` 0.6.5. Could be an old bug that has been resolved already. Can you upgrade and try again?

Comment: That worked! I upgraded both igraph C library and python extension to version 0.6.5. The dot file is written properly now.